# Using Angular 2 Google Maps Places to load nearby hospitals

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am currently trying to create a page that will locate where a user is, and then use the Google Maps places library to show the hospitals near them.

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqwYYp) is a perfect example of what I want to show when I load the page. But implementing that code has not been working effectively with my Angular/Ionic application.

First I began by loading the google maps library using

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js 
key=AIzaSyBuBzeYkYimIquGG5KkIcB6vFmtHMUzDFo&libraries=places" async defer>
</script>
```

And then inside of the component I created a `ngOnInit()` that would run the javascript found in the codepen. Except at the end of the function, I added `initMap()` so that it would initialize the map, as in the Codepen it is a callback on the script.

Secondly, I tried to get it working with Angular Google Maps but was again unable to get it to work. When I was trying to get it working with AGM, I was receiving the following error when trying to go to the page on which the map is located:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find control with unspecified 
name attribute
Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
at _throwError (forms.es5.js:1830)
at setUpControl (forms.es5.js:1738)
at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.es5.js:4520)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10812)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12238)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12177)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12880)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:12821)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MapPage.html:17)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12806)
at _throwError (forms.es5.js:1830)
at setUpControl (forms.es5.js:1738)
at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.es5.js:4520)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10812)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12238)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12177)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12880)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:12821)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MapPage.html:17)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12806)
at c (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:322)
at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:310)
at nav-controller-base.js:365
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:4149)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
```

But I'm not entirely sure that this problem has to do with AGM because after a second or two, a reference error appeared and said that `ReferenceError: google is not defined`.  I was getting this error earlier and I ran the command `npm install --save @types/googlemaps` in order to download the typings for google but still received this error even after I did that.

To reiterate, I am attempting to use Google Maps Places to load hospitals near a user, but am unable to get this working with Angular, but the Codepen linked above is the functionality that I wish to bring to my application, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the codepen you linked, the script call has a param to know which function it will use for its callback `&callback=initMap`:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBuBzeYkYimIquGG5KkIcB6vFmtHMUzDFo&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>`

You are getting the `ReferenceError: google is not defined` because the script is called asynchronously and your initMap() is being called ahead of time, before the script loads. So just do the same as what's done in the codepen.